# How to convert an existing column to a foreign key that allows null values - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I have a Postgres database with table t and column fk_c. I want to convert the column to a foreign key that references c_id in table lookup_c and allows null values. How can I do this?

```
ALTER TABLE public.t ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_t_c" FOREIGN KEY ("fk_c" ) REFERENCES "public"."lookup_c" ("c_id");
```

does not work because there rows with null values in column fk_c and I get
*ERROR:  insert or update on table "t" violates foreign key constraint "fk_t_c"
DETAIL:  Key (fk_c)=() is not present in table "lookup_c".*

Comment: A null value will not result in an error. What data type is `fk_c`?

Comment: It is a text field. Sorry no, both fk_c and c_id are citext fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that you have empty strings in that column, not `null` values.

You need to set those values to `null` before creating the foreign key:

```
update t
  set fk_c = null
where trim(fk_c) = '';
```